# How can I convert string into an imported alias in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got an image folder that contains images of playing cards and I imported them as follow:

```
import D2 from "../image/D2.png";
import H2 from "../image/H2.png";
import S2 from "../image/S2.png";
```

and all the way until I reach SA (Spade Ace)

I also have key value pair dictionary such as:

```
  1: "C2",
  2: "D2",
  3: "H2",
  4: "S2",...
```

I need this dictionary to both calculate the rank of the card and to generate image.

atm I can retrieve the value by evaluating the last char of the string and convert it into int (in case of K,Q etc I have a switch case for them)

My issue is I have trouble to convert the string into the alias that I imported.
I tried doing `eval(4)` but it didn't work.

if I modified the dictionary into

```
  1: C2,
  2: D2,
  3: H2,
  4: S2,...
```

I can easily use this as the `src`  of my images, but I can no longer use the card-code to obtain the value of the card.

Could you please suggest a solution or a better approach for this problem.

Comment: What is rank of a card in this context?

Comment: Why not have a config file: `{ C2: { value: 2, type: 'club', src: './image/C2.png' } }`. Then you don't need to jump through hoops - everything is one place. The value is `C2.value`, and the image source is `C2.src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow the question properly can't you just create the dictionary in this manner? If you intend to use card codes to obtain the value / image then you could build your dictionary like so:

```
dict = {
  C2: { image: C2, value: 1 },
  D2: { image: D2, value: 2 },
  ...
}

c2Image = dict['C2'].image;
```